# Does anyone has the experience of using the new p4 replicate command in their Perforce back-up /restore script?

Tags: backup, perforce, restore, disaster-recovery

we recently performed an upgrade of our whole perforce system to 2009.02

During this exercise, we noticed that the back-up /restore process that was installed here by the Perforce consultant a year ago was not completely working. Basically, the verify command has never worked (scary !).

As we are obliged to revisit our Back-Up/Restore scripts, I was toying with the idea of using the new p4 replicate command. The idea is to use it alongside an rsync of the data files, so that in case of crash we will lose at worst an hour of work (if we execute them every hour).

Does anyone has the experience or an example of back-up/restore scripts using the p4 replicate command of the 2009.02 version ?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is almost one year old, but if you are still curious, I implemented exactly what you are talking about.  I did it around the time you asked the question, but I didn't know about this site.
rsync'ing along metadata replication works great - we still use it in production.
The replica age varies, but most of the time it is less than several minutes.

--Mike

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, in the latest version 2010.2 the [p4 pull](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/pull.html#1048868) command copies the versioned files as well as the metadata, so there's no need for a separate rsync.

Comment: We have done some experience with p4 pull in version P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2010.2/279478 (2011/01/03) and it was not working properly ! We are doing a major upgrade this Summer, maybe the very latest version is better. But thx gareth.